# Node.js redis pub/sub missing message

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, redis, publish-subscribe

I'm trying to debug this code from two days and I cannot figure it out so I am asking you. 
The code is pretty simple: two endpoints that do almost the same thing.
The first one, 's', listen for any messages on channel 'idS'. If after 10 seconds it does not receive anything, it ends. If the req.body is not empty, send it to 'c'.
In the second one, 'c', always send a message to 'idS' and wait for a message on channel 'idC'. 
In 's' the variable 'id' is set to 1 so 'c' can understand when 's' is online.

 I have two different test programm (one for each endpoint). 
In testS I call the endpoint WITHOUT the req.body, when I receive an answer I call the endpoint again, this time with req.body. 
In testC I simply call the endpoint and wait for the answer. When I receive it, I call the endpoint again AFTER one second.

The test should work in this way:

1. s connect, it has nothing to send but listen on channel 'idS'.
2. c connect, listen on channel 'idC' and send "test" on 'idS'.
3. s receive on channel 'idS' the message "test" and quit.
4. A new s connect, listen on channel 'idS' and send a message to c on 'idC'.
5. c receive on channel 'idC' and quit.
6. A new c connect again after one second and repeat from 2.

```
var express = require('express'),
    redis = require('redis'),
    util = require('util'),
    client = redis.createClient(6379, 'localhost');
var router = express.Router();

router.post('/s', function(req, res){
    var id = req.query.code;
    var cId = "c_" + id;
    var sId= "s_" + id;

    //BUILD RESPONS
    var respons = {....};

    var clientSub = redis.createClient(6379, "localhost");
    clientSub.on("message", function(channel, msg){
        if(timeoutId)
            clearTimeout(timeoutId);
        client.del(id);
        respons.val = idS;
        clientSub.unsubscribe(idS);
        clientSub.quit();
        res.send(respons).end();
    });
    clientSub.subscribe(idS);
    client.set(id, 1);

    if(req.body){
        client.publish(idC, JSON.stringify(req.body));
    }

    var timeoutId = setTimeout(function(){
        if(!res.headersSent){
            clientSub.unsubscribe(idS);
            clientSub.quit();
            client.del(id);
            console.log(" HUB TIMEOUTED " + id);

            res.json(respons).end();
        }
    },1000*10);
});

router.post('/c', function(req, res){    
    var id = //code to get id
    var idC = "c_" + id;
    var idS= "s_" + id;


    var clientSub = redis.createClient(6379, "localhost");
    clientSub.once("message", function(channel, msg){
        var respons = {};
        respons.data = msg;
        clientSub.unsubscribe(idC);
        clientSub.quit();
        res.json(respons).end();
    });
    //subscribe to a channel
    clientSub.subscribe(idC);


    //try to send message
    client.get(id, function(err, reply){
        if(err)
            console.log(err);
        else if(reply == 1){
            client.publish(idS, "test");
        } else{
            console.log("ERROR!!!");
        }

    });
});
```

The problem, appartently, is that 'c', sometimes, does not receive the message on 'idC' (or s does not send it??).
The bug is not in the test programs.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Solved with then-redis. The problem was a sync one.